# Pushing Data to Another ViewController Without Moving ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, variables

I am relatively new to coding in Swift. I am trying to pass data back to another view controller without having to segue to that controller so that the user can stay on the same screen. I am looking into using a delegate and wondering if this will be the best way to access the variable on multiple view controllers. Thank you

View controller 1:

```
func passVariables() {


    let passSleepValue = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbHome") as! sbHomeController
    passSleepValue.getSleepValue = sleepValue




    //navigationController?.pushViewController(passSleepValue, animated: true)


}
```

View Controller 2:

```
    func updateDay() {






    let dayScoreAvg = getSleepValue

    dayScore.text = String(format: "%.1f", dayScoreAvg)

    print("Get sleep Value is \(getSleepValue)")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can already pass data to second ViewController but you can't pass some data back.

So one way is using **delegate pattern**.

Start with declaring delegate protocol with method for passing data (in your case it can be just passing `String`)

```
protocol SecondVCDelegate: class {
    func passText(_ text: String)
}
```

then create `delegate` variable in second ViewController

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: SecondVCDelegate?
    ...
}
```

Now you can implement this protocol to first ViewController

```
extension ViewController: SecondVCDelegate {
    func passText(_text: String) {
        // do something with text passed from second VC
    }
}
```

now set `delegate` of Second VC as `self` before you push it

```
func passVariables() {

    let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbHome") as! sbHomeController
    viewController.getSleepValue = sleepValue
    viewController.delegate = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

}
```

then in second VC you can just call method on your `delegate` and in first VC this method gets called

```
delegate?.passText("Hello First!")
```